# Как получить буквенную часть url (preg_match)?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь получить часть url, цифры получить удалось, а буквы никак не получается.

Помогите, пожалуйста, верно составить выражение.

Вид url  `https://www.site.tv/@igogi87/audio/121`

Мой код:

```
    if (!preg_match('/^https:\/\/www.site.tv\/([@a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/audio\/([0-9]+)/i', $url, $url_params)) {
    die('Wrong url');
    }
    $one_id = (int)$url_params['1'];
    $two_id = (int)$url_params['2'];
```

`$one_id` у меня равен 0

Comment: Выражение корректное. У вас возвращается две группы `@igogi87` и `121`. А то что `one_id` число, а возвращается строка, это правильно?

Comment: $one_id у вас int, а надо string

Comment: @Pashok, спасибо!